# How to use FreeTDS with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, freetds

I'm a newbie on Mac development, I need to access sql server from cocoa app via FreeTDS but I don't know how to do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I find that sort of work easiest if you just take the source code of the project and include it in the Xcode project and compile it all.

Later, you can build it as a framework or library in a separate target, but no need to that from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try that.